# How to calculate the distance of Mercury's perihelion shift in meters?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, celestial-mechanics, solar-system, precession

Since the shift in mercury's perihelion shift is 2.88E-5 degrees and mercury's altitude above the Sun at its perihelion is 46001200000 meters, can I use the formula for an isosceles triangle to calculate the perihelion shift in meters at 46001200000 meters? Something like:

**(2.88E-5)/2 = arcsin (?/46001200000)**, then solve for the unknown. Would that work?